# Scrapy download error and remove_request error

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

**Author note:** You might think that this post is lacking context or information, that is only because I don't know where to start. I'll gladly edit with additional information at your request.

---

Running scrapy I see the following error amongst all the link I am scraping:

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.fifa.com/fifa-tournaments/players-coaches/people=44630/index.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 75, in _deactivate
    self.active.remove(request)
KeyError: <GET http://www.fifa.com/fifa-tournaments/players-coaches/people=44630/index.html>
2016-01-19 15:57:20 [scrapy] INFO: Error while removing request from slot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 140, in <lambda>
    d.addBoth(lambda _: slot.remove_request(request))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 38, in remove_request
    self.inprogress.remove(request)
KeyError: <GET http://www.fifa.com/fifa-tournaments/players-coaches/people=44630/index.html>
```

When I run scrappy simply on that single URL using:

```
scrappy shell http://www.fifa.com/fifa-tournaments/players-coaches/people=44630/index.html
```

No errors are occurring. I am scrapping thousands of similar links with no problem but I see this issue on ~10 links. I am using the default `180` seconds download timeout from scrappy. 
I don't see anything wrong with these links in my web browser too.

The parsing is initiated by the request:

```
  request = Request(url_nrd,meta = {'item' : item},callback=self.parse_player,dont_filter=True)
```

Which is handled in the functions:

```
  def parse_player(self, response):
    if response.status == 404:
       #doing stuff here
      yield item
    else:
      #doing stuff there
      request = Request(url_new,meta = {'item' : item},callback=self.parse_more,dont_filter=True)
      yield request

  def parse_more(self, response):
    #parsing more stuff here
    return item
```

Also: I didn't change defaults settings for download retries in scrappy (but I don't see any retries in my log files either).

**Additional notes:**
After my scraping completed and since `dont_filter=True` I can see that links that failed to download with the previous error at some point, didn't fail when called in previous and subsequent requests.

**Possible answer:**
I see that I am getting a `KeyError` on one of the spiders and that de-allocation of that spider failed (`remove_request`). Is it possible that it is because I am setting `dont_filter=True` and doing several requests on the same URL and that the key of the spider seems to be that URL? That the spider was de-allocated by a previous, concurrent request on the same URL?

In that case how to have a unique key per request and not indexed on the URL?

---

**EDIT**

I think my code in `parse_player` was the problem, I don't know for sure because I edited my code since, but I recall seeing a bad indent on `yield request`.

```
  def parse_player(self, response):
    if response.status == 404:
       #doing stuff here
      yield item
    else:
      paths = sel.xpath('some path extractor here')
      for path in paths:
        if (some_condition):
          #doing stuff there
          request = Request(url_new,meta = {'item' : item},callback=self.parse_more,dont_filter=True)
        # Bad indent of yield request here!
        yield request
```

Let me know if you think that might have caused the issue.

Comment: a very interesting problem, I think you should share more spider code and maybe some middlewares if you are using them.

Comment: @eLRuLL Unfortunately I have completely changed my scrapy code since that post. I filter all my request now which is much better and I don't see that issue anymore (therefore I think somehow `dont_filter` is the culprit here.
While editing my code, I remember seeing a potential issue that could  have caused the issue:
- either creating a request in `parse_player` and never yielding it.
- or I was yielding a request that I never created in the first place.
Unfortunately I can't tell you much more as my code structure is quite different now. Feel free to close that question btw.

Comment: I am editing my post in order to try to reflect what the issue was.

Comment: @vrleboss I just wrote a simple spider to scrape the URL posted in your question, I did not get any error at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And if you simply ignore the errors ??

```
 def parse_player(self, response):
    if response.status == 200:
      paths = sel.xpath('some path extractor here')
      for path in paths:
        if (some_condition):
          #doing stuff there
          request = Request(url_new,meta = {'item' : item},callback=self.parse_more,dont_filter=True)
        # Bad indent of yield request here!
        yield request
```